# Help with a 2x3 contingency table significance test

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

MD here completely new to doing my own statistics

In a study I'm currently working on, I have three groups that I am assessing for a various categorical Yes/No Variables, for example:

[image]

Without thinking much about it, I programmed the table as is into R and performed Fisher's exact test (I assume it automatically runs a Freeman-Halton extension?). For most of the variables, the results were non-significant. For some, they were significant at a=0.05. In these cases, which post-hoc for between-group difference should I be doing? Should I do Fisher's exact test on 2x2 tables comparing each variable? Should I have done that in the first place rather than the first Fisher?

Thanks for any advice, I'm still quite a stats noob.

Comment: A chi-squared test on all three groups is not significant. It seems you don't have enough data in Group 3 to find significant differences involving that Group. Please say what differences you find to be significant, and (if relevant) give your rationale for picking two groups out of three for a test.

Comment: Hello, it's true in this particular contingency table the Fisher and Chi square is NS, so I don't need to compare any two groups. However, one of my contingency tables is 0/26, 2/36 and 4/8 (yes/no) and this gives me a significant result. To then determine which two groups differ significantly, would I do 2x2 Fisher tests?